# How do I show the avatar image when hovering over an text/link? (html, CSS)

Tags: php, css, image, popup, hover

I create a member list and all members are listed by a php request.
That works fine so far, but now I want that the avatar image just shows up, when hovering over the member name.

Right now, the image shows up at the beginning of the line, as in the image1.
[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzw8J.png)

It would be nice that the image just shows up, when hovering over the name of a member, like image2.
[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4znJ.jpg)

The Code for the related php request is this. In the figure-tag is the avatar and in the first and second "printf" line is the name.

```
<div class="wp-team-member wp-team-list-item author-<?php echo esc_attr( $user->ID ); ?> <?php echo esc_attr( $role_class ); ?>">
<figure class="wp-team-member-avatar author-image">
    <?php echo wp_team_list()->get_avatar( $user ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
</figure>   

<?php
if ( '' !== $last_name  ) {
    printf( '<p class="wp-team-member-description"><a href="#"><strong>%s, ', wp_kses_post( $last_name ) );
    printf( '%s</strong> </a>- ', wp_kses_post( $first_name ) );
    printf( 'LK Jahrgang %s - ', wp_kses_post( $lk_jahrgang ) );
    printf( '%s, ', wp_kses_post( $ehem_schule  ) );
    printf( '%s, ', wp_kses_post( $position ) );
    printf( '<span style="color:red;">%s</span>, ', wp_kses_post( $farbe ) );
    printf( '%s, ', wp_kses_post( $billing_address_1 ) );
    printf( '%s ', wp_kses_post( $billing_postcode ) );
    printf( '%s</p>', wp_kses_post( $billing_city  ) );
}
```

If anyone could help me with this, I'd appreciate this a lot.
As you can see in the printf-lines, I'm still a php rookie ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this as simple or complicated as you like. At it's most basic, you could do something like this:

```
.wp-team-member figure { display: none; }
.wp-team-member:hover figure { display:block; }
```

However, depending on the structure of your containing element you may want to toggle the `opacity` from to 0 to 1 rather switching the display mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate,

that was really simple.

Regards